# There exists definition for continuous spaces with weight?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, interpolation

There exists definition for continuous spaces with weight?

I am not sure if exist for example definition for $e^{\gamma t }C_{b}(\mathbb R_{+}^n)$ where $C_{b}(\mathbb R_{+}^n)$ is the continuous and bounded space for functions in $\mathbb R^n$. I did not found that definition in literature. ¿Is okay if i define this space as below?
For $\gamma<0$

$$e^{\gamma t }C_{b}(\mathbb R_{+}^n):=\{ e^{\gamma t}f(x): f\in C_{b}(\mathbb R_{+}^n) \}$$

with norm $||g||_{e^{\gamma t }C_{b}(\mathbb R_{+}^n)}= ||e^{\gamma t}f||_{C_b}$ where $g(t,x)=e^{\gamma t}f(t,x)$ with $t\geq 0$ and $x\in\mathbb R^{n-1}$?

There is something like this in literature? If somebody knows please i will appreciate any reference. Thank you

Comment: it is not very clear to me in your definition of norm: you are saying $\|g\|_{e^{\gamma t}C_b(\mathbb R^n_+)}=\|g\|_{C_b(\mathbb R^n_+)}$?

Comment: Sorry by confusion @Giulio R, i mean if i take $g\in e^{\gamma t}C_b$ then $g=e^{\gamma (.)}f$ with $f\in C_b$. I woul like to define $||g||_{e^{\gamma (.)}C_b}=?$ but the first thin was as i put above . Do you see something like these? Thank you